# Can the Haskell prelude functions be reduced to a set of core functions?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Can the Haskell prelude functions be reduced to a set of core functions, such that all other functions can be defined in terms of the core set? If so, what are the core functions?

Comment: Not _all_ but many of the prelude functions concerning lists can be written in terms of `Foldable.foldr`. For example: `map`, `filter`, `concat`, `and`, `all`, `maximum`, `length`...

Comment: I think what you are looking for are modules like `GHC.Prim` or [`GHC.Base`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html) that basically define the implementation interface of built-in data types. Everything else in the prelude is bootstrapped from them, defined in terms of Haskell itself.

Answer (score 5):

I have just walked through the `Prelude` documentation on Hackage. The only two operations I couldn't imagine implementing in "unadorned" Haskell are `error` and `seq`. In the case of `error`, I could even imagine implementing something in unadorned Haskell with the right denotational semantics, but which did not share the operational semantics of printing to the console.

There would of course need to be some cooperation between the execution engine for `IO` actions and the implementation of `IO` operations, but the operations themselves could reasonably be implemented in unadorned Haskell, e.g. with a free monad over the actions available in the Prelude.

It should not be surprising that such a tiny core is possible; after all, even the boring old lambda calculus can emulate all manner of interesting data types.